# Unsupported expression node type: Lambda

Tags: content-search

I implemented a simple search on Sitecore 8.1 and it works

I copied the same example for Sitecore 8.0 and got some error

> Unsupported expression node type: Lambda

http://sagepath.com/blogs/development/articles/sitecore-8-basic-search

It uses the same Lucene, ContentSearch DLL version, the only difference is the Sitecore Version (8.0/8.1)

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code that is causing the error? Also when you say its using the same `ContentSearch` dll version, if you are different versions of Sitecore, this should be different - if you have copied an 8.0 `ContentSearch` dll into an 8.1 installation - that will cause you problems.

Comment: Have you looked into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815826/sitecore-contentsearch-linq-unsupported-expression-node-type-parameter

Comment: Is the code you are using, exactly like that in the link? If so, it sounds like you have a dll issue. Use beyond compare you bin to a vanilla bin directory from the Sitecore zip file.

Comment: The code is exactly like the link,, i did not copy the dlls from 8.1 to 8.0, their installation are like it was before, i just made a comparison between those dlls to see what is the difference